# Mechanisms of binary/multiple star formation

Tags: formation, binary-star, mass, star-formation, initial-mass-function

What are mechanisms of binary/multiple star formation in different mass ranges (low, intermediate and high stellar masses)?

Comment: What do you mean by "diapasons"?

Comment: I mean low (approximately < 1 Solar mass), intermediate (≈ 1-8 Solar masses) and high stellar masses (> 8 Solar masses)

Comment: Is there a reason you are framing this question in relation to the stellar mass of the binary star(s)? From the reading I've done since looking at this, the questions around formation are more about the distances between the bodies, not their mass...

Comment: It can't be wrong to link to the talks held at the Space Telescope Science Institute. Here is a very recent presentation of precisely this topic: https://webcast.stsci.edu/webcast/detail.xhtml?talkid=3917&parent=1 It seems to be poorly understood. One idea is that large protostellar discs can be gravitationally unstable and fragment into the formation of a binary star system. (The talk is mainly on observations, because it is suggested that more of it is needed).

Comment: The talk I linked to above is by John Tobin of NRAO on Mars 11, 2014.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to comment...

I think this might help you understand the formation or binary and more stars systems. This of course is not the only possible method but it might explain the systems with big mass differences.

As the initial rotation speed increases (marked in the videos as beta) you will see how the protoplanetary disk breaks up and form more than one protostar.

http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/people/mbate/Animations/prestellar_discs.html